# Using of main theorems in differentiability.

Tags: real-analysis

I need hint for the first question , and for the second does my answer correct?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint for the first question: intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct for the second one. More generally, because differentiability is a local property, if $E$ is a union of two disjoint intervals, $f$ can do whatever it likes on each interval and still be differentiable, so we can't conclude anything about the monotonicity of $f$.

For the first one, you need to find a root of $f(x+1)-f(x)$, a continuous function on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: I need more if you please.

Comment: @FaisalJamal Can you use the Intermediate Value Theorem to find a zero of $f(x+1)-f(x)$ in $[0, 1]$?